# Swift local notification, show a viewcontroller and pass data

Tags: swift, notifications

So I create a local notification and use Realm primary key to identifying what object the notification was created for. Now when the notification shows and the user click yes I want to show a specific viewcontroller and load it with the object that created it.

I have gotten so far that I can get the primary key out of the notification but I am at a loss on how to show a specific viewcontroller and pass the object into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eg. if you have two viewcontroller. fristVC and secondVC
you want to try some event in secondVC and you want to effect in firstVC right.
**so first of all you have set this two line code in firstVc**

```
 NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: “NotifinationName”), object: nil)
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(StnNotificationExist(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotifinationName"), object: nil)
```

and this func also in FirstVc

```
@objc func StnNotificationExist(_ notification:NSNotification)
{      
  if let objId = notification.userInfo![“objId”] as? Int
  {
     // Your code here
     print(objId)
  }   
}
```

In secondVC set this code in click event

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:  "NotifinationName"), object: nil, userInfo: ["objId":1] )
```

if you want to show firstVC with update you want to **set push or pop viewcontroller after this line of code**